# I suggest that vs I suggest doing. Does one of these sounds more idiomatic than the other?

Tags: word-choice

I'd like to know which one of the following sentence is used more?

- I suggest doing your homework.
- I suggest that you do your homework.

**Edit:
Does one of these sounds more idiomatic than the other?**

Comment: I think a better (more accurate) question would be: _Does one of these sound more idiomatic than the other?_ If they both sound acceptable, would you really care if one was used 60% of the time, and the other 40% of the time? English is flexible and there is often more than one way to say essentially the same thing.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for the comment. Well, I'll gonna edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on the context.  To me

> I suggest doing your homework.

Has more immediacy, as in

> I suggest doing your homework, now!

and is equivalent to

> I suggest you do your homework.

whereas

> I suggest *that* you do your homework.

would have more the meaning of

> It would be good idea to do your homework *at some point*.

Comment: It's interesting that you think the gerund noun form has more "immediacy". The construction *I suggest [that] you [do something]* can only mean that doing [whatever] ***is what I think you should do***. But consider a context like *"I wonder what could have caused my stomach ache", "I suggest **eating those unripe apples**"*, where the speaker certainly isn't recommending that as a good course of action! So arguably the gerund form is ***less*** "immediate", since it can refer to a past action rather than a "current" recommendation.

Comment: ...put another way, it seems to me *I suggest [that] you XXX* is effectively a watered down version of *XXX* as a blunt imperative (in this example, the instruction *Do your homework!*). An imperative seems more "immediate" to me than most constructions.